# How to improve the speed of FTP directory listing with proftpd on Debian 7.5?

Tags: performance, ftp, directory-listing

I install proftpd on a VPS running Debian 7.5 hosted on Linode.com. The server location is in California (US) while I am remoting from Singapore.

The server is on SSD and I am using ADSL 100Mbs connection (supposed to be fast).

However I realize the speed of FTP directory listing is pretty slow - it takes 2-3 seconds to navigate between folders.

Meanwhile I have another FTP server (running FileZilla) located in South East Asia, running on a normal HDD - the directory listing is way faster.

Is there anyway I can improve the speed of directory listing in proftpd ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the latest stable version of proftpd (1.3.5) then there is bug when using TLS:

http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4108

> TJ Saunders 2014-09-24 02:46:33 UTC
>
> Pull request opened which fixes the issue:
>
> https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/pull/48
>
> Short version: we do NOT want the TCP_CORK/TCP_NOPUSH socket option
>   enabled on the data connection socket during the SSL/TLS handshake. 
>   This option, like Nagling, causes the socket buffer to wait to be
>   filled, up to some timer.  Hence the delay.

Solution? Get current git and compile.